# Can't add Angular Google Maps (AGM) to Jhipster

Tags: angular, google-maps, jhipster, angular-google-maps

I have followed the guide at https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/ while trying to integrate google maps to my app but doesn't seem to work at the moment. The map doesn't load and there is no error message on the console

.yo-rc.json

```json
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.sample"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.4",
    "baseName": "JhipsterExercise",
    "packageName": "com.sample",
    "packageFolder": "com/sample",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "db5d503363a3ec42c3fa113a44bf41b4ae63a29c",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

installed agm

```
yarn add @agm/core
```

import the script to vendor.ts

```json
import '../content/css/vendor.css';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import '@agm/core'
```

after editing the file i executed

```
yarn run webpack:build
```

app.module.ts

```typescript
import './vendor.ts';

import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { AuthExpiredInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor';
import { ErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/errorhandler.interceptor';
import { NotificationInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import { JhipsterExerciseSharedModule, UserRouteAccessService } from './shared';
import { JhipsterExerciseAppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { JhipsterExerciseHomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { JhipsterExerciseAdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { JhipsterExerciseAccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { JhipsterExerciseEntityModule } from './entities/entity.module';
import { PaginationConfig } from './blocks/config/uib-pagination.config';
import { StateStorageService } from './shared/auth/state-storage.service';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
// jhipster-needle-angular-add-module-import JHipster will add new module here
import {
    JhiMainComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProfileService,
    PageRibbonComponent,
    ErrorComponent
} from './layouts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        JhipsterExerciseAppRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        JhipsterExerciseSharedModule,
        JhipsterExerciseHomeModule,
        JhipsterExerciseAdminModule,
        JhipsterExerciseAccountModule,
        JhipsterExerciseEntityModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: 'THE-KEY-HERE'
        }),
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    ],
    declarations: [
        JhiMainComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        PageRibbonComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService,
        PaginationConfig,
        UserRouteAccessService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                StateStorageService,
                Injector
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                JhiEventManager
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                Injector
            ]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ JhiMainComponent ]
})
export class JhipsterExerciseAppModule {}
```

```typescript
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    account: Account;
    modalRef: NgbModalRef;

    lat = 51.678418; // the lat 
    lng = 7.809007; // the lon

    ....
```

And here is the home.component.html

```html
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

home.css

```css
agm-map {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: please creat a stackbliz

Comment: @PatricioVargas Hi Patricio, stackbliz would have been nice the only challenge is there are some extra settings configurations that comes bundled as part of Jhipster. But if you copy the .yo-rc.json into a new folder and run jhipster command then you'll get the whole sandbox app i am using on my end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue, looks like if the library is added at the root module

```
app.module.ts
```

Then somehow it doesn't get picked up correctly at the sub-module level so I added it to the target module and everything works fine

[image]